# I set my startup disk to Macintosh HD. But after opening it, the name becomes "/"

Tags: macos, hard-drive, applescript, startup

Using the System Preference -> Startup Disk I set my startup disk to Macintosh HD.  When I open it the name at the top of its window is "/". When I open the startup disk using Applescript it opens Macintosh HD, but the name of it becomes "/". Is this normal behavior?  My actual applescript code is this.

```
  tell application "Finder" to open startup disk    
  tell application "Finder" to get the index of Finder window "Macintosh HD"
```

But the 2nd line produces the error message

error "Finder got an error: Can’t get Finder window "Macintosh HD"." number -1728 from Finder
window "Macintosh HD"

if I replace 2nd line with:

```
tell application "Finder" to get the index of Finder window "/"
```

It gives me the expected answer of 1.

The image below shows the window Macintosh HD. Notice the name at the top of the window and the name at the bottom of the window. Can someone tell me if this is normal or do i have a problem?

[image]

Comment: Considering the various issues you've been having lately I'm starting to think your system is pretty messed up! Anyway, if I run the two   **Finder** lines of _code_ shown, they produce the expected results, assuming defaults are in play, and open the **Macintosh HD** and return `1` as expected.  Even from **Terminal**, `open /` opens to the **Macintosh HD** at the top center of the **Finder** _window_.

Comment: yea the smart status of my internal fusion drive is Failed but my computer is still crunching.  I'm not sure exactly what Failed means exactly.  Did it fail on one write attempt or Failed a number of times in a row.  My iMac is very slow.  Unless the Apple meeting Monday is a big disappointment, I expect new iMacs to be announced - ending some of these maddening problems.

Comment: BTW What is the **sudoers** _file_  doing in the _root_ of the **Macintosh HD** when it belongs in `/private/etc`?

Comment: I have no idea.  i noticed it when I made that image.  Don't remember moving it there. Should I move it back to /private/etc ?

Comment: The sudoers file is zero bytes so I assume it is empty.

Comment: @jmh you should really look into your SMART status. Disk Utility's SMART info is very generic. Download a SMART viewer and check to see which drive is damaged, and how severely. You should also make sure your backup is in working order

Comment: That just looks like you have the defaults set to show the POSIX path in the Finder window.

Comment: @red_menace:  How did that get set and how do I unset it?

Comment: Not sure how it was set, but from the Terminal, you can use `defaults write com.apple.finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle -bool false` to just use the name - you may also need to restart the Finder.

Comment: @red_menace. Thank you very much. That worked!!  Now my Macintosh HD has the name Macintosh HD!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Finder** normally uses the folder name in its window titles, but a preference can be set to show the POSIX path.  From the **Terminal**, the following command will set the preference, where `true` will show POSIX paths, and `false` will just use the name - in earlier systems the **Finder** may need to be restarted for it to take effect (the `killall` part):

```
defaults write com.apple.finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle -bool false; killall Finder
```

Answer (score 2):

Macintosh HD is the partition name. The mount point is `/`, however. Other volumes are mounted in the `/Volumes/` directory, such as `/Volumes/MyDisk`, if MyDisk is the name of the partition. This is similar to how Windows operates, where the boot disk is always C:\.

I'm not sure why Finder is showing it as /, though. On both my Mojave and Sierra machines, it shows "Macintosh HD". I don't have the bottom info bar, so that may be the reason.

Comment: Yes, but when i use the applescript line:  tell application "Finder" to  open "Macintosh HD" it works fine.